# Strapi Unsupported protocol issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodes, strapi

**Strapi Application.**

I am getting this issue on opening admin panel content manager for every content type

> Unsupported protocol /content-manager/content-types/api:"

Please tell me where is that coming from I need to make it correct

Also getting this error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “script-src ‘self’”. Either the ‘unsafe-inline’ keyword, a hash (‘sha256-rwMOiOeVICH7/Cjy5SkreID3OOi5HTrit357k22hUDQ=’), or a nonce (‘nonce-…’) is required to enable inline execution.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was the axios. I downgraded the version and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error, this helped me:

In file config/middleware.js I added

```
          "script-src": [
            "'self'",
            "DOMAIN-NAME-WHERE-SCRIPT-LOCATED.herokuapp.com",
          ],
```

[image]

[image]